# Wrong document root after giving dedicated IP to an account

Tags: ssl, dns, wildcard, cpanel, whm

I'm trying to assign a dedicated IP to an account on my cPanel/WHM installation and I get the default cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi showed when I try to access the website...

When I ping the domain on both my server and at home, I get to good IP (suppose it's 1.1.1.1).

I take a look into /var/cpanel/userdata/website.com (website.com is an example) to see if the documentroot is correctly set and also the IP. Everything is fine. (for ssl and non-ssl)

After, I take a look into the /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf to see if everything was correctly configured and it's also good.

I check if the DNS zone was correctly updated and it is.

I have used WHM to assign the new IP so it should work (I have done this before and everything was fine...).

I use the latest stable version of cPanel/WHM.

When I try to access the link website.com/lol.php, it look into /usr/local/apache/htdocs/ not in /home/website/public_html ...

Also, the SSL work, but not the non-ssl (yesterday I've added a new wildcard SSL to my domain).

Comment: it's a matter of webserver configuration, not of nameserver. Resolving already to the correct ip address is all DNS can do for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a third party product : Varnish.

I had to refresh the address pool to get it working.